# if [ 0 ] returns true. why?

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement

I'm now learning shell-script. Anyway, I run the below program.

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo rmmod my_driver
make clean
make
sudo insmod my_driver.ko   // return value is 0
var=$?
if [ $var ];
then
        echo " $var, not done!!"
else
        echo " $var, done!!"
fi
```

The output is,

```
...
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-431.11.2.el6.x86_64'
0, not done!!
```

In C language(I believe in any language), if `if` condition returns `false` it'll execute `else` block.

```
I tried below conditions too, but I faced same problem

if [ "$var" ]
if [ "$var" -eq "0" ]
if [ $var -eq 0 ]
if [ $? ]
```

Why it is not executing `else` block?
How can I execute `else` block for `if [ 0 ]`?

Comment: remove the semicolon on the if command.

Comment: I tried but no improvement

Comment: Since 0 means success, you'd probably want `if [ $var -ne 0 ] `

Comment: @nos Yes that is working. But I want to know reason.

Comment: You can try [[ ]] with if.

Comment: @SGG In a test with [  ]  `if [ $var ]` tests if $var is empty/doesn't exist -  it's not like `if (var)` in C where 0 means false and anything else is true. So as you might write `if (var != 0)` in C , you write `if [ $var -ne 0 ]` in a shell script. `-ne` means "not equal".

Comment: In your case, it's better to do: `if sudo insmod my_driver.ko; then echo "done!!"; else echo "not done!!"; fi`. You don't need an auxiliary variable to check the exit status of a command.

Comment: @SGG I have given a link in my answer, please refer the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Passing *any* string to the `test` command, i.e. `[`, would succeed.  So

```
if [ 0 ]
```

is equivalent to

```
if [ 1 ]
```

or

```
if [ foobar ]
```

You could make use of the arithmetic context instead, and say:

```
if ((var)); then
```

or, using the `test` command as:

```
if [ $var -eq 0 ]; then
```

Comment: how to execute `else` then?

Comment: @SGG `if ((var)); then ...` -- refer to the edit above.

Comment: @SGG The reason is mentioned in the first line of the answer.  `0` is a non-empty string so the condition evaluates to true.

Comment: @SGG: if you look at `help test`, you will notice that `-n STRING` and `STRING` are the same and the result is: *True if string is not empty*.

Answer (score 4):

If you want it to execute the else block if 0, then you have to set it so the condition is anything but 0.

As variables in bash are considered a string, using arithmetic operators (-ne, -gt, -eq) etc, will make it interperet it as a number.

In C you would have to set this as an int/bool for it to use equate to false when 0.

```
if [[ $var -ne 0 ]];then
    echo " $var, not done!!"
else
    echo " $var, done!!"
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

please try [[ test statement,

atleast following will work:

```
if [[ "$var" -eq "0" ]]
if [[ $var -eq 0 ]]
```

Why other would not work, well thats because

anything like :

`if [ $? ] or if [ "$var" ]`

is considered as true in bash

**[For difference between the [ and [[](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031)**

Comment: For testing arithmetic values use `(( ))`, they are easier more intuitive and less error prone.

Answer (score 2):

*In C language(I believe in any language)* : there's your problem.

I find it easier to consider that `if` does not test for true or false but for success or failure.  That makes it easier to reconcile the effect of zero, since zero is defined as success.

In Bash, `true` and `:` are built-ins (not constants or literals) and both give success.

If you use the `test` command `[ ]`, (or even `[[ ]]`) then values resolve to strings:

```
echo "hello"
if [ $? ]
then
    echo "True"
else
    echo "False"
fi
```

Gives **True**.

However, if you use the `arithmetic` test `(( ))`, then zero *is* "false":

```
echo "hello"
if (( $? ))
then
    echo "True"
else
    echo "False"
fi
```

Gives **False**

If you think about it, that is the same behaviour as C, where `'0'` (a `const char`) will give true but `0` (an `int`) will give false.  That's why if you want a binary zero `char` in C you use `'\0'`.

A language where zero (string or numeric) acts as true is Ruby (only nil and false are not true).

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
[[ $var -ne 0 ]] && echo "$var, not done!!" || echo "$var, done!!"
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you run `man test`. `if` does nothing but check the return command of the subsequent command, and `[` is an alias of `test`.

Looking at the man page for `test` you'll find that if the expression you feed it is just a single string it defaults to testing if the string is of non-zero length.

If you want to test for the test for the *numeric* value of zero, the you *must use* `[ $? -eq 0 ]`

It's also worth noting that bash is not C, especially in that a return code of zero is construed as `true` and non-zero values are `false`.

Answer (score 0):

If you test single value in traditional mathematical sense, then `expr` may do the job instead of `test`:

```
if expr 0; then echo TRUE; else echo FALSE; fi
```