# Shell script : How if condition evaluates true or false

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

What environment variable or something internally the '`if`' keyword checks to decide true/false.
I am having something like below two statements. `abc` is mounted , but not `pqr`.

```
if mount |grep -q "abc"; then echo "export pqr"; fi
if mount |grep -q "pqr"; then echo "export abc"; fi
```

In the above case I expected first statement to do nothing since `abc` is mounted(so finds the row in mount o/p) hence the `$?` after `mount |grep -q "abc"` is 0. 
And I expected second statement to execute the echo. But it's happening otherwise, first statement is printing but second not. So want to understand on what basis if decides true/false.
[Here is one related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23426497/if-0-returns-true-why)

But the accepted answer for that question says :

```
if [ 0 ]
is equivalent to

if [ 1 ]
```

If this is true then both my statements should do echo, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a basic difference between the commands that you are issuing and the analogy that you are drawing from the referenced question.

When `grep` is executed with the `-q` option, it exits with a return code of zero is the match is found.  This implies that if the output of `mount` were to contain `abc`, then

```
if mount |grep -q "abc"; then echo "export pqr"; fi
```

is equivalent to saying:

```
if true; then echo "export pqr"; fi
```

Note that there is no `test` command, i.e. `[`, that comes into the picture here.

---

Quoting from the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins):

> The `test` and `[` builtins evaluate conditional expressions using a set
>   of rules based on the number of arguments.
>
> 0 arguments
>
> ```
> The expression is false.
> ```
>
> 1 argument
>
> ```
> The expression is true if and only if the argument is not null.
> ```

This explains why `[ 0 ]` and `[ 1 ]` both evaluate to true.

Answer (score 1):

The `if` command does not act, like C-like languages, on the "boolean value" of an integer: it acts on the **exit status** of the command that follows. In shell, an exit status of 0 is considered to be success, any other exit status is failure. If the command following `if` exits with status 0, that is "true"

Example:

```
$ test -f /etc/passwd; echo $?
0
$ test -f /etc/doesnotexist; echo $?
1
$ if test -f /etc/passwd; then echo exists; else echo does not exist; fi
exists
$ if test -f /etc/doesnotexist; then echo exists; else echo does not exist; fi
does not exist
```

Note that `[` and `[[` are (basically) commands that (basically) alias `test`

Answer (score 0):

```
if [ 0 ]
```

tests to see if the string `0` is non-empty.  It is non-empty, so the test succeeds.  Similarly, `if [ 1 ]` succeeds because the string `1` is non-empty.  The `[` command (also named `test`) is returning a value based on its arguments.  Similarly, grep returns a value.
The `if` keyword causes the shell to execute commands based on the value returned by the command, but the output of the command preceded by `if` is irrelevant.

The command `test 0` (equivalent to the command `[ 0 ]` returns a value of 0. The command `test 1` also returns a value of 0.  Zero is treated by the shell as a success, so the commands of the `if` clause are executed.